# Local notifications are not coming on the datetime I want

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I'm working with local notification. I got the notifications working. But I'm struggling with setting the correct date.

Let me first sketch the situation. I am making a festival app. This festival is on the 28-29-30 JUNE. Every artist object has an art_day. This can be 1 - 2 or 3.

```
 1 --> 28 JUNE
 2 --> 29 JUNE
 3 --> 30 JUNE
```

I want a local notification 15 min before the start time of the artist. So this is how I'm making my fireDate of the notification.

```
-(NSDate *)getDateForArtist:(Artists *)artist{
    int day = [artist.art_day intValue];
    int timeStart = [artist.art_timestart intValue];
    NSString *timeStart2 = [self getTimeStamp:artist.art_timestart];
    int hours = [[timeStart2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)]intValue];
    int minutes = [[timeStart2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,2)]intValue];
//in my db timeStart looks like 1530 --> 15h30 (I know bad db structure!!!)
    int day2;

    if(day == 1){
        NSLog(@"day is 28");
        day2 = 28;
    }else if (day == 2){
        NSLog(@"day is 29");
        day2 = 29;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"day is 30");
        day2 = 30;
    }
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
    [comps setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [comps setDay:day2];
    [comps setMonth:06];
    [comps setYear:2013];
    [comps setHour:hours];
    [comps setMinute:minutes];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"date is %@",date);


    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setMinute:-15];
    NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:date options:0];
    NSLog(@"date -15 min %@", date2);
    return date2;
}
```

This is how I create my notification

```
   UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                            init];
        if (notifyAlarm)
        {
            NSDate *datePush = [self getDateForArtist:artist];
        NSLog(@"artist plays on: %@ on hour %@",artist.art_day,artist.art_timestart);
        NSLog(@"Push notification should send on: %@",datePush);
            notifyAlarm.fireDate = datePush;
            NSDictionary *dicNotification = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:artist.art_id,@"pushKey", nil];
            notifyAlarm.userInfo = dicNotification;
            notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
            notifyAlarm.soundName = @"Glass.aiff";
            notifyAlarm.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ starts in 15 minutes",artist.art_name];
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
            NSLog(@"Added");
        }
```

But for some reason I don't get any push notification. Or I think that the date is not correct.

This is what I get from my logs

```
2013-06-29 15:37:17.801 genkonstage[14120:907] artist plays on day: 2 on hour 2020
2013-06-29 15:37:17.803 genkonstage[14120:907] Push notification should send on: 2013-06-29 20:05:00 +0000
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: You are retreiving date from database, so when you save date in database it takes into consideration time difference also.So when you save date just remove time difference from local time and save and while retreiving also remove time difference and use.Hope I am clear.

Comment: But when I log DatePush I get the correct time ?

Comment: Why are you using timezone ?

Comment: Try stating a local notification for 10 seconds into the future and get that to work with your app first.

Comment: I'v tried with the 10 seconds and that was working